# WKWebview does not loading local image in Swift

Tags: swift, wkwebview

i am using WKWebview to show my local htm file. Everything was good, but when i added local picture to my htm files, pictures didn't seem. Lots of stackoverflow user had similar problem but there is no clear answer. here is my code ;

```
    var a = dic["adi"]?.asString()
    var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(a, ofType: "htm" )
    var url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:path!)
    var request = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)

    var theConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()

    theWebView = WKWebView(frame:self.view.frame, configuration: theConfiguration)

    var error:NSError?
    let text2 = String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)

    if let theError = error
    {
        print("\(theError.localizedDescription)")
    }

    theWebView!.loadHTMLString(text2!, baseURL: nil)
    self.view.addSubview(theWebView!)
```

i hope you can help me. i am waiting your answers. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in WKWebView.

You can wait for 8.2 with fixes or use dirty hacks (local HTTP server).

Answer (score 2):

The trick to display local images within local HTML files with **WKWebView** is defining the baseURL within the **loadHTMLString** method.

My code example is in Objective-C but you will get the idea:

```
    NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: resourcePath];

    [self.webView loadHTMLString: htmlBodyString baseURL: baseURL ];
```